# Сравнить элементы таблицы и словаря

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица. Она логирует историю перехода записи в таблице из статуса в статус

| id | status_id | time_add |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 14-10 |
| 1 | 1 | 13-12 |
| 1 | 7 | 12-12 |
| 2 | 3 | 14-09 |
| 2 | 6 | 14-08 |
| 2 | 7 | 14-06 |
| 3 | 1 | 13-11 |
| 3 | 3 | 12-10 |
| 3 | 1 | 12-09 |

Таблица вытащенат с помощью пандас. Так же данные отсортированы по id и времени (время в порядке убывания.)
`req_2 = pd.DataFrame(mobile_records_2)`

Так же есть словарь допустимых переходов из статуса в статус по типу

`dict_1 = {'1':'2', '2':'3', '1':'4', '2':'5', '5':'2', }`

Переход из статуса в статус - комбинация рядом стоящих значений столбцыа status_id.
Т.е для id = 1, переходы из статуса в статус были следующие:
7 - 1 - 0
(0 - конечный и самый новый статус)
в 12 -12 запись с id(1) находилась в статусе(7)
затем в 13-12 изменила статус на (1)
и в 14-10 завершила переход и осталась со статусом(0)
Вот в чем вопрос, как можно сравнить соответствует ли переход из статуса в статус записей таблицы разрешенным переходам в словаре?

Comment: для вас, естественно, абсолютно ясно, что такое «переход из статуса в статус», «разрешённый переход» и т.п. // но для тех, кому вы задаёте вопрос, расшифруйте это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: Да, покажите, как должны искаться в датафрейме соответствия словарю

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , Постарался исправить, надеюсь стало понятнее. Извините, я тут в первый раз. Не пинайте сильно

Comment: Ага, ну тогда можно сделать `groupby` по столбцу `id` и потом применить аггрегацию, и вот уже для аггрегации сделать функцию, которая будет проверять допустимы ли переходы по словарю, ей на вход будет поступать `pandas.Series` я так понимаю. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812998/8324991

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, А зачем тут `groupby`, если уже все отсортировано?

Comment: а у вас словарь неполный? переход из 7 в 1 - разрешен?

Comment: @Nommad Так вас переходы внутри одного `id` же интересуют? Или между разными `id` переходы тоже должны проверяться? Вы не путайте сортировку и группировку. Группировка нужна, чтобы смотреть переходы между `status_id` внутри одного `id`.

Comment: @strawdog, это просто как пример. Там сама таблица на ~1000 записей и словарь где-то на 250 значений. Я ведь все сюда не запихну)

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, меня интересуют переходы `status_id` в рамках  одинаковых `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так. Только учтите, что у словаря не может быть больше одной записи с одинаковым ключом. Если вам такое нужно, вам придётся переделывать со словаря на список кортежей. И я поменял одну запись в словаре, чтобы хоть один переход был легальным:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def func(series):
    for a, b in zip(series[1:], series):
        if dict_1.get(a) != b:
            print(f'Ошибочный переход: {a} -> {b} ({dict_1.get(a)})')

dict_1 = {'1':'2', '2':'3', '1':'3', '2':'5', '5':'2', }

data = """id    status_id   time_add
1   0   14-10
1   1   13-12
1   7   12-12
2   3   14-09
2   6   14-08
2   7   14-06
3   1   13-11
3   3   12-10
3   1   12-09""".split('\n')
data = list(map(str.split, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

_ = df.groupby('id')['status_id'].agg(func)
```

Вывод:

```
Ошибочный переход: 1 -> 0 (3)
Ошибочный переход: 7 -> 1 (None)
Ошибочный переход: 6 -> 3 (None)
Ошибочный переход: 7 -> 6 (None)
Ошибочный переход: 3 -> 1 (None)
```

В скобках - значение словаря для такого ключа перехода, если ключа вообще нет в словаре, то будет `None`.

Comment: А со списком кортежей это как будет выглядеть ?

Comment: Ну, тогда придётся идти по этому списку и искать есть ли переход. Наверное, оптимальнее тут будет словарь с ключом откуда переход и множеством куда может быть переход. Тогда проверять будет не сильно сложнее, чем в коде из моего ответа.

Comment: Просто если, например, разрешенных переходов не два, а три. Вы вроде сами недавно, что все значения в словаре должны быть уникальными. Можно разве тогда делать пары ключ : значение `(1:2), (1,3)`?

Comment: Коллекции можно вкладывать друг в друга. В словаре должен быть уникальным только ключ. Поэтому варианты 1>2, 1>3, 1>4 можно разместить в словаре так: `{1: {2, 3, 4}}`, то есть вложить в словарь в качестве значения **множество**. Ключ - откуда переход `1`, значение - множество возможных переходов `{2, 3, 4}`.

Comment: Ооо, спасибо большое. Не знал

Comment: А проверка тогда будет как-то так: `if not b in dict_1.get(a, {}):`

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

не берусь судить насколько эффективен этот код, привожу просто как альтернативу:

```
dict_1 = {'1':'2', '2':'3', '1':'4', '2':'5', '5':'2', '1':'3', '6':'3', '1':'0'}
#-------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--добавил

df['valid'] = (df.groupby('id')['status_id'].
               transform(lambda x: pd.concat([x.shift(-1),x],axis=1).apply(tuple,axis=1)).
               isin(dict_1.items()))
print(df)

  id status_id time_add  valid
0  1         0    14-10   True  # распознан
1  1         1    13-12  False
2  1         7    12-12  False
3  2         3    14-09   True  # распознан
4  2         6    14-08  False
5  2         7    14-06  False
6  3         1    13-11  False
7  3         3    12-10  False  # переход не распознан
8  3         1    12-09  False
```

как уже сказал в своем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1426578/457260) @CrazyElf, ключи в словаре должны быть уникальны (переход 1->3 не распознался из-за неуникальности ключа '1')

```
>>> dict_1.items()

dict_items([('1', '0'), ('2', '5'), ('5', '2'), ('6', '3')])
```